# How to vectorise if condition with a pandas Series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to avoid apply() and Instead vectorize my data processing.

I have a function that buckets data based on few "if" and "else" conditions. How do I pass data to this function?

```
def my_function(id):
    if 0 <= id <= 30000:
       cal_score = 5
    else:
       cal_score = 0

    return cal_score
```

Apply() works, it loops through every row

But, apply() is slow on a huge set of data. (My scenario)

```
df['final_score'] = df.apply(lambda x : my_function(x['id']), axis = 1)
```

Passing a numpy array does not work!!

```
df['final_score'] = my_function(df['id'].values)
```

ERROR : "truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.call()

Its not liking the entire array being passes as the "if" loop in my function errors out due to more than 1 element

I want to update my final_score column based on ID values but by passing an entire array.

how do I design or address this ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Series.between` to create your condition, multiply the resultant mask by 5.

```
df['final_score'] = df['id'].between(0, 30000, inclusive=True) * 5
```

Comment: Nice convenience method, I just checked, and unfortunately it doesn't do anything nifty to avoid the double numpy operation. I think `numpy.ndarray` should have this to begin-with, it being such a common operation.

Comment: This created my new column 'final_score' and updated with score '5' for the rows I needed. But rest of the data in that 'final_score' ended up being NaN (default ?)

So, should I now write another condition to hit rest of those rows and update columns appropriately ?

Sounds like a bad design, am I missing something ?

Comment: @abhi655 No, check my updated answer, I've already addressed that.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy:

1. Convert Series to numpy array via '.values'

   n_a = df['final_score'].values
2. Vectorize your function

   vfunc = np.vectorize(my_function)
3. Calculate the result array using vectorized function:

   res_array = vfunc(n_a)

   df['final_score'] = res_array

Check https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html for more details

Vectorized calculations over pd.Series converted to numpy array can be 10x times faster than using internal pandas calculations

Comment: this guy vectors